# Работа с чужими окнами С#

Tags: c#, windows

Как в C# работать с чужими окнами системы Windows? Через какой-то встроенный класс или через импорт DLL:

```
using System.RuntimeInteropService;
....
public class PInvokeClient
{
       [DllImport("user32")]
       public static extern int FindWindow(string ClassName,string lpWindowName );
       public static Main(String[] args) 
       {
               int HWND = PInvokeClient.FindWindow(.....
       }
}
```

Благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так, но это не совсем с окнами, а скорее с процессами и их главными окнами:

```
...
Process.GetProcesses()[0].MainWindowHandle...//там много методов, но если интересует именно поиск по классу окна то это не подойдёт наверное.
...
```

Comment: Это что за библиотека?

Comment: System.Diagnostics

Comment: Спасибо большое! А не подскажете еще, к окнам Windows можно обращаться все-таки только через WinAPi, или есть иные способы.

Comment: Вас что именно интересует? "Под капотом" это по любому будет через вин апи, но в рамках .net и C# это моветон использовать winApi напрямую, хотя и можно.

Comment: Т.е иного выхода, кроме  System.Diagnostics нет?

Comment: Что значит "иного выхода"? Можно написать врапер на вин апи, можно скачать готовые библиотеки, можно поглубже почитать документацию по .net и, может, обнаружиться функционал под ваши задачи. Вариантов много, вопрос чего хочется. Но я сомневаюсь что идеология .net будет заточена под работы с окнами других приложений, скажем так - незаконно. Есть большой функционал по взаимодействию с другими программами, но, так сказать, по обоюдному согласию.

Answer (score 0):

А что Вас интересует в "чужих" окнах Win? Послать WM_MESSAGE сможете. В принципе, я так поступал, когда в свою программу встраивал запуск калькулятора и блокнота Win, потом искал их по FindWindow и, соответственно, запрещал повторный запуск или закрывал при закрытии своей программы (WM_CLOSE или WM_QUITE). Некоторые программы (когда-то проигрыватель WinAmp, а может и сейчас) имеют свой WinAPI для отправки им сообщений. Есть еще технология COM - в данном варианте лучше использовать механизм позднего связывания.

Comment: К примеру, изменить заголовок...впрочем, это уже вас не касается =)